# Parse, Function only works for the current user

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

The following function seems to only work for my Current user, any other ObjectId that I type into the input will return a Post (Bad Request) error in the console.

```
var query =  new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
var userInput = $('#inputObject').val();
query.equalTo("objectId", userInput);
query.first({
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result.id);
        result.set('money', 20);
        result.save();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("None found.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this is that the Parse user object is only modifiable by the current user. You can get around this by creating a Cloud Code function, which modifies the money value for the intended user. Note, the cloud code function must call `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` [Source](https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-allow-admin-user-write-access-to-another-user)

**CloudCode Function:**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setMoney", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.userId);
    query.first({
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result.id);
            result.set('money', 20);
            result.save();
            response.success();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("None found.");
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

**JavaScript Call**

```
Parse.Cloud.run("setMoney", {userId: userInput}, {
    success: function(result) {
        // Success
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // Error
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't type $, just parse deploy. I went back to the [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60795/room-for-dehli-and-nottobrag).